# Is there a way to create a composition of two functions

Tags: python-3.x, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to compose a two functions using the scypy `compose()` built in function, but I keep getting wrong answers.

While using Mathematica, the built in function `Composition[]` would provide an appropriate answer if I would compose a function. In Python I used `compose()` function but without any luck.

Code in python

```py
from sympy import*
x = Symbol("x")
compose(2/x,x+1)
```

Code in Mathematica

```
Composition[2/x, x + 1][x]
```

Python ignores the second function `x+1`, and gives the result as `2/x`. If the first function would be `2*x`, then the python would result in `2*x+2`, as the composition should be.

Comment: Strange behavior. It seems it works as expected only as long as both inputs are polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

Following an answer to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30637437/how-to-do-function-composition-in-sympy):

```py
from sympy import *

x = Symbol('x')
h = 2 / x
g = x + 1
f = h.subs({'x':g})
```

Worked for me and `f` returned `2 / (x + 1)`.