# sympy function compose - bizzare results

Tags: sympy

I'm trying to compose two functions and I get a bizzare result
'''

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from sympy import *
init_printing(use_unicode=True)
x= symbols('x')
f = x/(x+1);
g = x/(x+2);
print(compose(f,g))
```

This shows : x/((x + 1)*(x + 2))

Should be x/(2x+2)

I don't get it. Does anyone has an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite being available in the top-level `sympy` namespace under the plain name `compose`, `sympy.compose` doesn't actually do general function composition.

`sympy.compose` is actually [`sympy.polys.polytools.compose`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html?highlight=compose#sympy.polys.polytools.compose). It's actually a function for polynomial composition. When you try to compose `x/(x+1)` and `x/(x+2)`, it ends up interpreting these inputs as multivariate polynomials in 3 variables, `x`, `1/(x+1)`, and `1/(x+2)`, and the results are total nonsense.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there a way in sympy to compose such functions?