What mathematical formula can I use that will simulate the same process as using the current result in the next result?
I'm coding in python and when I print a variable called result multiple times and use the same name result as a parameter it will update the new value each time while using the previous result.
I'm looking for a mathematical formula that can do this because I'm using sympy and it is meant to be used for mathematical processes.
The code I want you guys to look at is:
result = 10

# Use the current result in the next calculation
result = result  + 5 

result = result + 5 

result = result + 5

result = result + 5
print(result)  # Output: 25

In this code, I can use the same name variable result which will update each time while using the previous value.
I want a mathematical formula that does this. I'm not looking for a mathematical formula that describes how to get 25 from the results, I'm looking for the effect of having the current result and using it in the next result each time.
Can you guys help me find a formula for this?

are you referring to recursion?

The term to look for is "function composition". for example, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30637437/how-to-do-function-composition-in-sympy

That should print 30, not 25. And the formula looks like simply result = 10 + 5 * 4

Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2190817

How did you get 25? Should be 30

result = 10;
result += 5*4;
print(result);

@iBeMeltin I'm looking for a closed form mathematical formula but anything without loops

@bogovicj I will look into this. Is it a mathematical formula?

@Barmar I'm not looking for a mathematical formula for the problem. I'm looking for a mathematical formula that can describe using the current value in the next value

Then result += 5 * 4

If you are looking for math formulas, then this is off-topic, this is a programming site, not a math one.

@Dr.Snoopy I'm looking fir a mathematical formula I can implement in python in sympy

Still you are looking for a math formula, here we discuss about the implementation. People already linked you that there is a whole math site in the network.

@Barmar += is getting there but if I use this in my sympy summation will it use the previous value of what x was?

@user27394478 If you have a formula that you don't know how to implement, it is related to this website

@medhi ahmadi brother do you think if I use += it will work? I want to use this in my summation but I don't know if it will take the last value of x and use it in the next value of x. I'm talking about sympy summations

Talking about formulas, nothing actually stops you from making yours. It's Python and you can make your own formulas and even libraries with few lines of codes. I'm guessing that what I gave you in my earlier comment is actually what you're looking for but you're unable to communicate it properly. Moreso you haven't shown us the implementation of this summation in sympy. Some users here might not be familiar with that library. Please provide an MRE.

I suggest you completely rewrite the question and focus on the problem you want to solve with sympy, and where you get stuck. Make it concrete.

@trincot is there a way we can chat so I can show you or can you freelance this for me because I can pay for this

If you are looking to hire a programmer, then there are lots of sites and companies on the internet for that. This is the wrong place for that.

Hello user27394478, you must reference the variable inside the function, with the reserved word global, something like: val = 44
print( val )
def cal():
global val
val += 3;
cal()
print ( val )
